# How to use JSON data from api in frontend

Tags: node.js, json, postgresql, express

I followed [a tutorial](https://blog.logrocket.com/setting-up-a-restful-api-with-node-js-and-postgresql-d96d6fc892d8/) for making an api with express and postgres. I can get all my data in json form no problem. But I have no idea how to use the data in the frontend of a site.

These are what I have in 2 different files that are linked.

*index.js:*

```
const db = require('../queries')

router.get('/classes/:id', db.getClassById)

router.get('/classes/:id/edit', db.getClassById, (req, res) => {
    res.render('dashboard/editClass')
})
```

*queries.js:*

```
const getClassById = (req, res) => {
    const id = parseInt(req.params.id)
    pool.query('SELECT * FROM classes WHERE state = 1 AND classId = $1', [id], (err, results) => {
        if(err){ 
            throw err
        }
        res.status(200).json(results.rows)
    })
}

module.exports = {
    getClassById
}
```

The getClassById query is called by the express middleware and automatically sends the json data to the page, which will not allow the res.render('dashboard/editClass') to work.

So how would I call this query so that I can fill in a form with the data from the query so a user can see the existing data and make any changes they want?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to do the work of two routes in one route. Typically you *either* return json for an ajax call *or* you render a template as html for the browser..

Comment: For that what you want, you should use 2 seperate routes, one for rendering your template, one as API endpoint which returns JSON data

Comment: @Marc so that means for rendering the template, I should be fetching the data with fetch or XMLHttpRequest and I will be calling a route like '/api/classes/:id'?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Mark and Marc who commented, I realized I needed to fetch the data from my own api when rendering the front end pages. I am now using axios to get this done in node and so far it is doing exactly what I was looking for.